# Performance of a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 (using to purge records from a table)

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database purge process that uses a stored procedure to delete records from a huge table based on `Expire Date`, it runs every 3 weeks and delete about 3 million records.

Currently it is taking about 5 hours to purge the data which is causing lot of problems. I know there are lot of efficient way to write the code, but I'm out of ideas, please help me to the right direction.

```
--Stored Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_Expire_StoredValue_By_Date]
     @ExpireDate DateTime, @NumExpired int OUTPUT, @RunAgain int OUTPUT 
AS
   -- This procedure expires all the StoredValue records that have an ExpireDate less than or equal to the DeleteDate provided
   -- and have QtyUsed<QtyEarned
   -- invoked by DBPurgeAgent

   declare @NumRows int  

   set nocount on  
   BEGIN TRY    
     BEGIN TRAN T1  

        set @RunAgain = 1;  
        select @NumRows = count(*) from StoredValue where ExpireACK = 1;  

        if @NumRows = 0 
        begin  
           set rowcount 1800;  -- only delete 1800 records at a time  

           update StoredValue with (RowLock) 
           set ExpireACK = 1 
           where ExpireACK = 0 
             and ExpireDate < @ExpireDate 
             and QtyEarned > QtyUsed;  

           set @NumExpired=@@RowCount;  
           set rowcount 0  
        end  
        else begin  
           set @NumExpired = @NumRows;  
        end  

        if @NumExpired = 0 
        begin  -- stop processing when there are no rows left  
           set @RunAgain = 0;  
        end  
        else begin  
            Insert into SVHistory (LocalID, ServerSerial, SVProgramID, CustomerPK, QtyUsed, Value, ExternalID, StatusFlag, LastUpdate, LastLocationID, ExpireDate, TotalValueEarned, RedeemedValue, BreakageValue, PresentedCustomerID, PresentedCardTypeID, ResolvedCustomerID, HHID)  
                select 
                   SV.LocalID, SV.ServerSerial, SV.SVProgramID, SV.CustomerPK, 
                   (SV.QtyEarned-SV.QtyUsed) as QtyUsed, SV.Value, SV.ExternalID, 
                   3 as StatusFlag, getdate() as LastUpdate, 
                   -9 as LocationID, SV.ExpireDate, SV.TotalValueEarned, 
                   0 as RedeemedValue, 
                   ((SV.QtyEarned-SV.QtyUsed)*SV.Value*isnull(SVUOM.UnitOfMeasureLimit, 1)), 
                   PresentedCustomerID, PresentedCardTypeID, 
                   ResolvedCustomerID, HHID   
                from 
                   StoredValue as SV with (NoLock) 
                Left Join 
                   SVUnitOfMeasureLimits as SVUOM on SV.SVProgramID = SVUOM.SVProgramID  
                where 
                   SV.ExpireACK = 1  

           Delete from StoredValue with (RowLock) where ExpireACK = 1;  
        end  

        COMMIT TRAN T1;  
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH  
       set @RunAgain = 0;  

       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN  
          ROLLBACK TRAN T1;  
       END  

       DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
       DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
       DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

       SELECT 
           @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
           @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
           @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

       RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);  
    END CATCH
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on `StoredValue` table? Could you please add definition of table and its indexes?

Answer (score 1):

Why you're running with this logic makes no sense to me.  It looks like you are batching by rerunning the stored proc over and over again.  You really should just do it in a `WHILE` loop and use smaller batches within a single run of the stored proc.  You also should run in smaller transactions, this will speed things up considerably.  Arguably, the way this is written you don't need a transaction.  You can resume since you are flagging every record.

It's also not clear why you are touching the table 3 times.  You really shouldn't need to update a flag AND select the rows into a new table AND then delete them.  You can just use an output clause to do this in one step if desired, but you need to clarify your logic to get help on that.

Also, why are you using `ROWLOCK`?  Lock escalation is fine and makes things run faster (less memory holding locks).  Are you running this while the system is live?  If it's after hours, use `TABLOCK` instead.

This is some suggested pseudo-code you can flesh out.  I recommend taking @BatchSize as a parameter.  Also obviously missing is error handling, this is just the core for the delete logic.

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) StoredValue
    SET <whatever>

    INSERT INTO SVHistory <insert statement>

    DELETE FROM StoredValue WHERE ExpireAck=1

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRAN
        BREAK;
    END

    COMMIT TRAN

END
```

Answer (score 0):

First look at what is causing it to be slow by looking at the execution oplan. Is it the insert statement or the delete?

Due to the calculations in the insert, I would suspect it is the slower part (unless you have triggers or cascade delete on the table). You could change the history table to have the columns you use in the calculation and allow nulls in the calculated fields. Now you can insert to that table more quickly and then do the delete. In a separate step in your job, you can then update the calculations. This would at least tie things up for a shorter period of time, but depending on how the history table is acccessed may or may not be possible.

Another out of the box possibility is to rename your table StoredValue to StoredValueRaw and create a view called StoredValue that only displays the active records. Then the job to delete the records could run every fifteen minutes or so and only delete a few records at a time. This might be far less disruptive to the users even if the actual deletes take longer. You still might need to put the records in the history table at the time they are identified as expired.

You should possibly rethink doing this process every three weeks as well, the fewer records you have to deal with the faster it will go.